# Calling puppet defined resource with multiple parameters, multiple times

Tags: puppet

I've got a simple puppet defined resource that looks like this:

```
define mything($number, $device, $otherthing) {
    file{"/place/${number}":
        ensure => directory
    }
    mount { "/place/${number}":
        device => $device,
        ensure => mounted,
        require => File["/place/${number}"]
    }
    file {"/place/${number}/${otherthing}":
        ensure => directory,
        require => Mount['/place/${number}']
    }
}
```

I need to call this resource a number of times with different parameters, but can't figure out how to do this without explicitly calling `mything()` repeatedly.

Ideally, I'd have all the parameters for the stored in some sort of array, and then just call `mything($array)`, a bit like this:

```
$array = [
    {number => 3, something => 'yes', otherthing => 'whatever'},
    {number => 17, something => 'ooo', otherthing => 'text'},
    {number => 4, something => 'no', otherthing => 'random'},
]

mything($array)
```

But this doesn't appear to work. I'm fairly sure this would work if my resource only took a single parameter and I just had a flat array of values, but can I do the same thing with multiple named parameters?

Comment: I've fleshed it out a bit - I had hoped the details weren't important and that there was a sensible generic way to do this.

Answer (score 7):

This may work for your case. Instead of defining the array in a variable, make them parameters when calling the `define` type.

```
define mything($number, $device, $otherthing) {
    file{"/place/${number}":
        ensure => directory
    }
    mount { "/place/${number}":
        device => $device,
        ensure => mounted,
        require => File["/place/${number}"]
    }
    file {"/place/${number}/${otherthing}":
        ensure => directory,
        require => Mount['/place/${number}']
    }
}

mything {
    "k1" : number => "3", device => "Yes", otherthing => "Whatever";
    "k2" : number => "17", device => "Noo", otherthing => "Text";
    "k3" : number => "5", device => "Oui", otherthing => "ZIP";
}
```

I haven't tested the entire thing, what I have tested is this `define` instead and it works:

```
define mything($number, $device, $otherthing){
  notify{"$device is $number not $otherthing":}
}
```

Results :

```
Mything[k1]/Notify[Yes is 3 not Whatever]/message:
Mything[k2]/Notify[Noo is 17 not Text]/message:
```

Comment: Interesting - didn't know you could do that. I guess my reason for wanting to put them into a variable is if I wanted to pass that structure off to more than one define, but this is certainly neater than what I had originally.